# Unable to load dynamic library 'zip' php - ArchLinux

Tags: php, archlinux

So I installed **php 7.2.5-2** on my **ArchLinux** distribution and when I run php I have this error:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip' (tried: /usr/lib/php/modules/zip (/usr/lib/php/modules/zip: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/modules/zip.so (/usr/lib/php/modules/zip.so: undefined symbol: zip_libzip_version)) in Unknown on line 0`

In my `/etc/php/php.ini` the lib is activated:

```
;extension=xmlrpc
;extension=xsl
extension=zip
```

And the lib `zip.so` exist but as the error is saying, there is an "undefined symbol"

`ls -la /usr/lib/php/modules` output:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  34680 May 10 22:27 bcmath.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  22704 May 10 22:27 bz2.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  31704 May 10 22:27 calendar.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  92016 May 10 22:27 curl.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  55888 May 10 22:27 dba.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  83824 May 10 22:27 exif.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  59248 May 10 22:27 ftp.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14192 May 10 22:27 gettext.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  67440 May 10 22:27 gmp.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  42928 May 10 22:27 iconv.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  71536 May 10 22:27 ldap.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 137152 May 10 22:27 mysqli.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 436776 May 10 22:27 opcache.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  26752 May 10 22:27 pdo_mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14192 May 10 22:27 shmop.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 313328 May 10 22:27 soap.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  92016 May 10 22:27 sockets.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14192 May 10 22:27 sysvmsg.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  10096 May 10 22:27 sysvsem.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14192 May 10 22:27 sysvshm.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  80080 May 10 22:27 xmlrpc.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  63568 May 10 22:27 zip.so
```

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: what does `ls -la /usr/lib/php/modules` output?

Comment: @bassxzero I edited the post to show you the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the solution, I installed `downgrader` on ArchLinux (`sudo pacman -S downgrader`) and used it do downgrade the version of php.

My guess is that **ziplib** is too "old" comparing to php version and haven't been updated to feet with **php 7.2.5-2**